# Existence of vector which implies null polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I've been struggling with this apparently simple question:
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator. 
Then there exists $v\in V$ such that if $f$ is a polynomial and $f(T)v=0$, then $f(T)=0$.
I ran out of ideas, any suggestions?

Comment: If $n$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial $g$, then it is enough to find a vector $v$ such that $v,Tv,T^2v,...,T^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent. This is because any polynomial $f$ can be written as $f(x)=g(x)h(x)+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$. Since $f(T)=a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+...+a_1T+a_0$, then $0=f(T)v=a_{n-1}T^{n-1}v+...+a_1Tv+a_0v$ would imply $a_0=...=a_{n-1}=0$. Therefore $f(x)$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial. The [rational canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) tells you how to find such a vector.

Comment: Can you solve the problem for $T$ diagonalizable?